# UISearchbar UI in iOS 12 and 13 are different and not correct

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, ios13, ios12

The UI in my searchbar is behaving differently than expected.

**I want it to look like this:**

[image]

**In iOS 13 it looks like this:**

[image]

**And in iOS 12 it looks like this:**

[image]

I am configuring the searchbar in ViewDidLoad with this:

```
    guard let searchField = searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField else { return }

    searchBar.backgroundColor = .red
    searchField.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.3)
    searchField.textColor = .white
    searchField.leftView?.tintColor = .white
    searchField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Search", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white])
```

Comment: What is the question here? Which design do yo want to achieve? You are just making a statement here. You should ask something with your findings. Regarding to your issue yes iOS 13 changed behaviour of UISearchBar. for iOS 13 you can directly reach searchTextField like this searchBar.searchTextField. You shouldn't get textfield with key value search.

Comment: Well as the code says i want a red background for the searchbar, transparent background for the searchtextfield, white search icon and white text for the placeholder

Comment: Edited the question

Answer (score -1):

I've tried to create your searchBar but I didn't test it. You can find answers to your questions from the code snippet. You need to add the **UISearchBar extension** also to your project to use some methods in the snippet.

```
searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
searchBar.searchBarStyle = .default
searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
searchBar.setTextFieldPlaceholderColor(color: UIColor.white)
searchBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
searchBar.setImage(UIImage(named:"searchIcon"), for: .search, state: .normal)
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    searchBar.searchTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.3)
    searchBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .any, barMetrics: .default)
    searchBar.searchTextField.textColor = UIColor.white
    searchBar.searchTextField.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)
} else {
    searchBar.removeBackgroundImageView()
    searchBar.setTextFieldBackground(color: UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.3))
}
```

**UISearchBar extension**

```
extension UISearchBar {

    //use for iOS 12 and below
    func removeBackgroundImageView(){
        if let view:UIView = self.subviews.first {
            for curr in view.subviews {
                guard let searchBarBackgroundClass = NSClassFromString("UISearchBarBackground") else {
                    return
                }
                if curr.isKind(of:searchBarBackgroundClass){
                    if let imageView = curr as? UIImageView{
                        imageView.removeFromSuperview()
                        break
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func setTextFieldBackground(color : UIColor) {
        for subView in self.subviews {
            for subView1 in subView.subviews {
                if subView1.isKind(of: UITextField.self) {
                    subView1.backgroundColor = color
                    (subView1 as? UITextField)?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func setTextFieldPlaceholderColor(color : UIColor) {
        for subView in self.subviews {
            for subView1 in subView.subviews {
                if subView1.isKind(of: UITextField.self) {
                    if let placeholder = (subView1 as! UITextField).placeholder {
                        (subView1 as! UITextField).attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string:placeholder,attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: color])
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work in iOS 12. You can not get UITextField with this way.